# How do I work with a comma-separated-string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hy there!

So we have some kind of array in our domain.

eg `[ 123, 234, 345 ]`

When we are going to query this against SQL Server, we usually transform this array to `123,234,345` (string), so that we can do something like (with string replace):

```
SELECT    *
FROM      [dbo].[myTable]
WHERE     [myColumn] IN (123,234,345)
```

This is pretty straight forward, even if a `WHERE [myColumn] = 123 OR ...` would be better when it comes to performance.

This (the way of transforming) is the only way to get the array from the domain to the database.

Now I need, to do a join, this array to be transformed to a table. The first thing which came to my mind was that I could create a XML inside the domain and transform this somehow. Can you give me any examples how to do so or even better solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure that you can use comma separate string and than [parse into table](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4680-Parse-comma-separated-string-SQL.aspx).

But i suggest to sent xml with ids like this:

```
<query id="59bd6806-d28c-451a-8473-69f1432e46b2">
  <ids>
    <id>1</id>
  </ids>
</query>
```

And than parse into table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetQueryIdsTable] 
(   
    @query xml
)
RETURNS @ids TABLE (id INT, ItemOrder INT)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @ids (ID, ItemOrder) SELECT Ids.Id.value('.','int'), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ROWCOUNT_BIG()) AS ItemOrder

    FROM @query.nodes('/query/ids/id') as Ids(Id)   

    RETURN 
END
```

After parsing you can join.

On the server side i use Xml builder like this:

```
public class Query
{
    private List<string> Ids = new List<string>();

    public void AddId(Int32 id)
    {
        if (Ids.Contains(id.ToString()))
            return;

        Ids.Add(id.ToString());
    }

    public String ToXmlString()
      {
        var idsElement = new XElement("ids");

        foreach (var id in Ids)
        {
            idsElement.Add(new XElement("id", id));
        }


        XElement query = new XElement("query",
                new XAttribute("id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            idsElement
         );

        return query.ToString();
       }

}
```

I like xml because you can what you want and easy parse at sql server.

Comment: :) your link made me laugh ... that's why i've left out the loop-variant in my question ;) ... yeah - the server-side was missed out, but that revealed the magic! THANKS!

Comment: @pst: that's part of CTE (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx), more info on ROW_NUMBER: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx